# Can't toggle the visibility of a menu

Tags: java, python, oop, jython

Win-10, JDK/JRE 1.8, NetBeans 8.2, Jython 2.7, Python 3.9

I'm a hobbyist programmer and my code base comes from on-line examples (thank you.) I did some procedural programming back in the 80's but I have a hard time making the jump to OOP. I see my root problem as not understanding how to find objects to manipulate; especially between classes.

I run DeskTopFrame to produce my GUI, from the menu all of my "_intro" actions work. Method "menu_pick" finds all my other actionPerformed and passes them to Class(Switcher) all the methods in Switcher work, I can open a a Jframe from Class(LocationPanel) in method "list_all_jmri_locations" (Book and/or on-line example recommendations will be warmly received.)

#### MY GOAL

I'm trying to filter the menubar from menu "Mode" and toggle the visibility of menu "Locations" such that when (mode=stand alone) the menubar displays "menu2a" and when (mode=JMRI) the menubar displays "menu2"

#### MY PROBLEM

Method menu_pick gives me the following error message:

> File
> "C:\Users\jwkel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JythonProject\src\desktop.py",
> line 40, in menu_pick
> if self.menu2.isSelected(): AttributeError: 'DesktopFrame' object has no attribute 'menu2'

I can't seem to figure out the proper way to point to "menu" or "menu2." I've tried using "self", "demo", "deskTopFrame" and just plain "menu2." I've tried treating it as a Jython Attribute and direct value assignment. I've tried to find a class method to use but they fail too.

If I move my test to Class(switcher) method "stand_alone" I get error message stating "menu2 not declared"

---

```
from javax.swing import *
from myTest import *
from javax import imageio
from java import io
from locationIntro import *
import sys
from switcher import *


class DesktopFrame(JFrame):
    """
    Base GUI code     By: Jim Kelly 12-6-20
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Creates the Main program frame
        """
        JFrame.__init__(self,
                        'Serial RFID Layout Monitor',
                        size=(1200, 700),
                        defaultCloseOperation=JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

        self.setLayout(BorderLayout())
        self.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
        self.create_menus()
        self.image("rfid_pic.jpg")
        self.text = '''Getting Started:\n\n1 - Connect the Hardware\n\n
        2 - Assign COMM port\n\n
        3 - Tell the program how many readers you have\n\n
        4 - Assign JMRI locations to readers\n''' 
        self.main_pane(self.text)
        
    def menu_pick(self, event):  
        '''Capture which menu item was selected'''
        c=event.getActionCommand()
        #print c
        if c == "Stand Alone":
            print "stand alone",c
            if self.menu2.isSelected():
                print "is selected"
            else:
                print "not selected"
        elif c =="JMRI":
            print "JMRI",c
            self.menubar.menu2a.visible=0
            self.menubar.menu2.visible=1
        #else:
        d = c.replace(" ","_")
        e = d.lower()
        a=Switcher()
        a.get_selection(e)

    def image(self, fileName):
        '''Put picture on the Introduction panels'''
        self.panel = JPanel()
        self.panel.setLayout(BorderLayout())
        self.panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
        _image_filename = fileName
        self.showImage = imageio.ImageIO.read(io.File(_image_filename))
        self.panel.add(JLabel(ImageIcon(self.showImage)))
        self.add(self.panel, BorderLayout.WEST)
        self.pack()
        
    def main_pane(self, text):
        ''' Put introduction text into mainPanel'''
        _text = text
        self.mainText = JTextArea()
        self.mainText.text = _text
        self.mainText.lineWrap = True
        self.mainText.wrapStyleWord = True
        self.mainText.setSize(400, 250)
        self.mainText.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
        self.mainScroll = JScrollPane(self.mainText)
        self.mainScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS)
        self.mainScroll.setPreferredSize(Dimension(400, 250))
        self.mainScroll.getViewport().setView((self.mainText))
        self.mainPanel = JPanel()
        self.mainPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
        self.mainPanel.add(self.mainScroll)
        self.add(self.mainPanel, BorderLayout.EAST)
        self.pack()
    
    def rfid_intro(self, event):  
        '''Basic setup instruction on Main frame'''
        self.mainPanel.visible = False
        self.panel.visible = False
        self.text = '''Getting Started:\n\n1 - ****** TEXT CLIPPED ******")
        
    def locations_intro(self, event):  
        '''About text explains what locations are.'''
        self.mainPanel.visible = False
        self.panel.visible = False
        self.text = ("Serial RFID Locations:\n\n "
            "NOTE: This menu is filtered ****** TEXT CLIPPED ******.")
        self.main_pane(self.text)
        self.image("locations_pic.jpg")  
        
    def engines_intro(self, event):  
        '''About text explains what engines are.'''
        self.mainPanel.visible = False
        self.panel.visible = False
        self.text = ("Serial RFID Engines:\n\n" 
            "Serial RFID uses the term ****** TEXT CLIPPED ******")
        self.main_pane(self.text)
        self.image("engine_pic.jpg")
    
    def readers_intro(self, event):  
        '''About text explains what readers are.'''
        self.mainPanel.visible = False
        self.panel.visible = False
        self.text = ("Serial RFID Readers:\n\n"
            "Readers are the location assignments.****** TEXT CLIPPED ******") 
        
        
        self.main_pane(self.text)
        self.image("readers_pic.jpg")
    
    def cars_intro(self, event):  
        '''About text explains what cars are.'''
        self.mainPanel.visible = False
        self.panel.visible = False
        self.text = ("Serial RFID Cars:\n\n"
        "NOTE: This menu is filtered acording to the mode you have seleccted.\n\n"
        "JMRI Mode:\n"  ****** TEXT CLIPPED ****** " ) 
        
        self.main_pane(self.text)
        self.image("cars_pic.jpg")
    
    def mode_intro(self, event):  
        '''About text explains what modes are available.'''
        self.mainPanel.visible = False
        self.panel.visible = False
        self.text = ("'Serial RFID Modes:\n\n "
        "Serial RFID has 2 modes of operation.\n\n ****** TEXT CLIPPED ******")
        self.main_pane(self.text)
        self.image("mode_pic.jpg")
        
    def create_menus(self):
        '''Main frame menu items'''
        menu = JMenu('File')
        menu.add(JMenuItem('About Serial RFID', actionPerformed=self.rfid_intro))
        menu.add(JMenuItem('Exit', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu1 = JMenu('Mode')
        menu1.add(JMenuItem('About modes', actionPerformed=self.mode_intro))
        alone = JRadioButtonMenuItem('Stand Alone', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick, selected=1)
        jmri = JRadioButtonMenuItem('JMRI', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick)
        bGroup = ButtonGroup()
        bGroup.add(alone)
        bGroup.add(jmri)
        menu1.add(alone)
        menu1.add(jmri)
        
        menu2 = JMenu('Locations',visible=0)
        menu2.add(JMenuItem('About RFID Locations', actionPerformed=self.locations_intro))
        menu2.add(JMenuItem('List all JMRI Locations', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick,visible=0))
        menu2.add(JMenuItem('Link JMRI Location to a Reader', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick,visible=0))
        menu2.add(JMenuItem('Compare a JMRI Location List to a Reader', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick,visible=0))
       
        menu2a = JMenu('A Locations',visible=1)
        menu2.add(JMenuItem('About RFID Locations', actionPerformed=self.locations_intro))
        menu2.add(JMenuItem('List Cars from a Reader', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick,visible=1))
        menu2.add( JMenuItem('Add Text Location to a Reader', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick,visible=1))
        
        menu3 = JMenu('Engines')
        menu3.add(JMenuItem('About RFID Engines', actionPerformed=self.engines_intro))
        menu3.add(JMenuItem('Create Engine', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu3.add(JMenuItem('Asign to location', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu3.add(JMenuItem('Pick up Car', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu3.add(JMenuItem('Drop off Car', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu3.add(JMenuItem('List Cars in Engine', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu3.add(JMenuItem('Terminate Engine', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu3.add(JMenuItem('Delete Engine', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu4 = JMenu('Readers')
        menu4.add(JMenuItem('About RFID Readers', actionPerformed=self.readers_intro))
        menu4.add(JMenuItem('Readers', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu4.add(JMenuItem('Add reader', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu4.add(JMenuItem('Delete reader', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick))
        menu5 = JMenu('Cars')
        menu5.add(JMenuItem('About RFID Cars', actionPerformed=self.cars_intro))
        menu5.add(JMenuItem('Read Car from JMRI list', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick,visible=0))
        menu5.add(JMenuItem('Assign RFID tag to Car', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick,visible=0))
        menu5.add(JMenuItem('Manual Mode Car Programming', actionPerformed=self.menu_pick,visible=1))
        
        menubar = JMenuBar()
        menubar.add(menu)
        menubar.add(menu1)
        menubar.add(menu2)
        menubar.add(menu2a)
        menubar.add(menu3)
        menubar.add(menu4)
        menubar.add(menu5)

        self.setJMenuBar(menubar)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo = DesktopFrame()
    demo.setLocation(30, 30)
    demo.show()
```

---

```
from locationIntro import *
import sys

class Switcher(object):
    '''Match menu selection to a function'''
    def get_selection(self, argument):
        """Convert menu text to a function"""
        method_name = str(argument)
        # Get the method from 'self'. Default to a lambda.
        method = getattr(self, method_name, lambda: "Invalid Pick")
        # Call the method as we return it
        return method()
 
    def exit(self): 
        '''end program'''
        sys.exit()
        
    def stand_alone(self): 
        '''end program'''
        print 'made 2a'
        
    def jmri(self): 
        '''end program'''
        print "made 2"
        
    def list_all_jmri_locations(self):
        ''' run JMRI XML file and get layout locations.'''
        m = LocationPanel()
        m.show()
        return "January"
 
    def link_jmri_location_to_a_reader(self):
        '''asign location(s) to a reader'''
        return "February"
```

****** Class clipped **********

Answer (score 0):

I went to the menu definitions (menubar, menu, menuitem) and added "self" to each entry and then in method menu_pick added the code as

```
def menu_pick(self, event):  
        '''Capture which menu item was selected'''
        c=event.getActionCommand()
        if c == "Stand Alone":
            print "pick stand alone"
            self.menu2.visible=0 
            self.menu2a.visible=1


        if c =="JMRI":
            print "pick JMRI"
            self.menu2.visible=1 
            self.menu2a.visible=0

            
        d = c.replace(" ","_")
        e = d.lower()
        a=Switcher()
        a.get_selection(e)
```

Now my menu visible toggle works.